# Cocoa - Display xib on another xib

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xib, nib

Can anyone tell me how (or direct me to info on) displaying a .xib (nib) on another .xib (nib).

How ever I wish to place it so I can programically move it around the main nib sort of like this (which obviously doesn't work)

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{

    NSRect customView = NSMakeRect(pos1, pos1, 200, 100);

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"secondXib" owner:self];

    NSRectFill (customView);
}
```

And I wish to do this for Mac OS X (Not iPhone). (By the way using xCode 4 incase it makes a difference)

Answer (score 10):

You can easily load a view from another nib using `NSViewController`. In your nib you should just set **File's Owner**'s custom class to `NSViewController` and hook up the `view` outlet of **File's Owner** to point to the view you want to load. You can then just do this:

```
//create an NSViewController and use it to load the nib
NSViewController* vc = [[NSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourNibName" bundle:nil];
//get the view from the view controller
NSView* loadedView = [vc view];
//release the view controller so we don't leak
[vc release];
//add the view as a subview of your main view
[mainView addSubview:loadedView];
//position the view
[loadedView setFrameOrigin:NSMakePoint(100.0, 100.0)];
```

You don't need to do anything in `drawRect:`. The subview will draw itself, and `drawRect:` will be called automatically if you move the subview.

You should read the [View Programming Guide for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). It is critical to understanding how views work, and it is clear from your question that you do not yet have that understanding.

You should also read the [Cocoa Drawing Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: How can I make connections from `YourNibName` to the controller that code goes in? (to clarify, not the `NSViewController* vc`, but the controller class containing all that code)

Comment: You can't, and shouldn't. The view controller should manage all of that, and it should talk to its owning object via delegate methods or some other method.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot, 
Another alternative ( which is basically the non programming way of doing it ), is to add a NSViewController object in your first xib, and set it to you use the nib name that you specify.
In your second xib, don't forget to set the class name in the "custom class" field on the view ( and NSViewController on file's owner ) else that won't work.