# Loading nib file from framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, cocoa

I have a nib file created from Interface builder which I have inserted in a framework as bundle resources and added to my project. I am trying to load the nib file from the framework but not sure how to load it for a ViewController. Could anyone share any thoughts as of how to load the nib file from main bundle of the framework resource folder?

Thanks.

Comment: [bundleObj loadNibFile: externalNameTable: zone:]

Comment: You don't need to do that. `NSViewController` knows how to load nibs from a bundle: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9757633/50122

Answer (score 1):

Okay so after wondering around a bit, I finally got it working. Below is the content as of how I loaded nib file from external framework, might help someone in future.

```
NSString *resourceBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TheFrameworkName" ofType:@"framework"];

NSLog(@"the bundle: %@",resourceBundlePath);

NSBundle* languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:resourceBundlePath];
[languageBundle load];

NSLog(@"The bundle desc: %@",[languageBundle description]);

self.scanManual = [[Scanner alloc] initWithNibName:@"Resources/Scanner" bundle:languageBundle];
```

Since I was getting (null) contents in first few tries, its a good way of checking of the bundle is getting loaded by keeping NSLog. Thanks again to stackoverflow community

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this will work for xib but This is how i am loading my images from bundle check if it is working for you.

But make sure that when you add your folder you should click on second radion button like image.

[image]

```
imageArray = (NSMutableArray *)[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"jpg" inDirectory:@"Beauty Shots_iPad"];
```

Comment: Amit, I am adding my framework twice, once as in framework, and another within the bundles so it can work as a point of reference for resources. The problem is, when I build a demo app, it never grabs the resources from the framework but the xyz.app location. I have used successfully the images though by using [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"WhiteLabelLibrary.framework/Resources/star_empty" ofType:@"png"]]]] however, not sure how to do this using a nib file. Thanks